# get json data by post function of jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I wanna to use post function of jQuery to send data to php code,the php code echo json.

```
$array = array(
           'error_no' => 0;
           'error' => 'error number 0'
              );
echo (json_encode($array));
```

that is my php code,now how should I get post somethings to this page and access error_no element in javascript var???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this before echo, so jQuery knows that this is JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

And then in javascript:

```
$.post('/the/url.php', post_data, function(json) {
    alert(json.error_no);
});
```

Comment: post_data should be at json format?
how should I convert it in javascript to json?

Comment: post_data should be either a javascript hash (like `{param: value}`, or a query string like `param=value&param2=value2` or anything returned by `.serialize()`)